# With a dataframe in pandas, how do I append a dataframe where only some columns are the same?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
             rootID   parentID    jobID    counter
          0    A         B          D         0
          1    E         F          G         0
          2    A         C          D         0
          3    E         B          F         0
          4    E         F          G         0
```

And one dataframe that looks like this

```
             rootID   parentID    StepID
          0    A         B          1     
          1    A         F          2      
          2    A         C          3    
          3    E         B          4    
          4    E         F          5
```

How can I append the second dataframe to the first dataframe based on the keys that they have in common, "rootID" and "parentID" such that I get

```
             rootID   parentID    jobID    counter   stepÌD
          0    A         B          D         0        Null
          1    E         F          G         0        Null
          2    A         C          D         0        Null
          3    E         B          F         0        Null
          4    E         F          G         0        Null
          5    A         B         Null      Null       1 
          6    A         F         Null      Null       2
          7    A         C         Null      Null       3
          8    E         B         Null      Null       4
          9    E         F         Null      Null       5
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try, `pd.concat`, pandas has intrinsic data alignment, therefore when using this function and most others, pandas will keep row index labels and column headers aligned:

```
pd.concat([df, df2], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

Output:

```
  rootID parentID jobID  counter  StepID
0      A        B     D      0.0     NaN
1      E        F     G      0.0     NaN
2      A        C     D      0.0     NaN
3      E        B     F      0.0     NaN
4      E        F     G      0.0     NaN
5      A        B   NaN      NaN     1.0
6      A        F   NaN      NaN     2.0
7      A        C   NaN      NaN     3.0
8      E        B   NaN      NaN     4.0
9      E        F   NaN      NaN     5.0
```

***Note:*** pandas has an unfortunate side-effect of converting numerical columns that contain NaN to float datatype.

Comment: Is it the same if we use`append`? There is any advantage using concat? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, see [these docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#concatenating-using-append).